# How to configure search to search by information inside of PDF documents

Tags: search, search-scope, search-results

I want to setup my search in a way that when I search for information or documents in my search site, it allows me to search using information inside the document.

What do I need to configure?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use and IFilter to crawl the content of PDF-documents. It should work out of the box for Office-documents.

Here's a [detailed tutorial](http://nickgrattan.wordpress.com/2010/06/14/adobe-pdf-ifilter-indexing-with-sharepoint) (I haven't tried it)

Comment: Thanks guys. 

100% working.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install an IFilter in Sharepoint. For example the Adobe PDF iFilter 9.0. More information on http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2293357